# Elements do not move to their correct place until the window is affected?

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I have a button that, when clicked, inserts some HTML onto the page in the form of `textarea`s. Upon the first click of the button, the first `textarea`s appear fine in the places that they should, but when I click the button two or more times the `textarea`s begin appearing in sporadic places (some on top of one another, some not adjusting for the ones above, etc.). However, as soon as the browser window is affected in any way (e.g. is windowed or maximized, or the Chrome Developer Tools are brought up with Ctrl+Shift+J) that causes the browser content to redraw, the `textarea`s instantly snap to their correct locations.

So to me, it seems as though my HTML/CSS is perfectly fine, it's just the browser needing to re-draw the content? I'm not positive this is the case, that's just my hypothesis.

Can anyone answer why this is happening and what I can do to fix it so that the new `textarea`s appear in the correct place every time the button is clicked?

<sub>Content before browser is affected in any way (right after clicking the button)</sub>
[image: Content before browser is affected in any way (right after clicking the button)]

<sub>Content after browser is affected in some way</sub>
[image: Content after browser is affected in some way]

If there's anything I can do to improve this question, please tell me instead of just downvoting and I will be glad to fix it! I am open to any criticism or willing to provide any necessary clarification!

**EDIT:** [Here is a jsfiddle with the just the code that is producing the problem (in the same visual style I have it).](https://jsfiddle.net/eLn1am2k/3/)

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(90, 90, 96);
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
}

div.addP {
  float: left;
  min-width: 50%;
}

input[type=text] {
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 137);
  border-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <script src="JavaScript/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var appendHere = document.getElementById("DateSpan0");
      var spanCounter = 1;

      $("#plus").click(function() {
        $("#plus").before("<br><input type='text' name='Loc' style='position:absolute;left:0;'>");
        var newSpan = "<br><span id='DateSpan" + spanCounter + "' style='position:absolute;left:0;'><input type='text' name='Date'>&nbsp;in&nbsp;</span>";
        appendHere.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newSpan);
        var newestSpan = "DateSpan" + spanCounter;
        appendHere = document.getElementById(newestSpan);
        spanCounter++;
      });
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body style="font-weight:bold; font-size:50px">

  <div class="addP">
    Location:
    <span id="textArea1" style="position:relative;">
            <input type="text" name="Loc1">
            <img id="plus" src="plus.png" height="30px" width="30px"style="position:absolute;left:210px;top:20px;">
          </span>
    <br>Date:
    <span id="DateSpan0" style="position:relative;">
            <input type="text" name="Date">&nbsp;in&nbsp;
          </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The best clarification would be the code that you are using. Can you possibly paste a snippet of the code in question, then we could actually run it in our browser to debug with you.

Comment: @NoahWhitmore Sure thing! Also, after more research it looks like this is all something that probably has to do with reflow? (like this guy says) https://www.paulirish.com/2011/dom-html5-css3-performance/

Comment: Possibly, it's kind of the inverse issue though. I've always thought of reflows as a thing that you want to avoid - the issue that you are having sounds like a reflow is what solves it. If you are adding to the DOM though, it should trigger a reflow automagically, can you paste the code that shows how you are adding the new HTML upon button click? EDIT* You added the code as I was writing this. Thank you.

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a minimal, **complete**, and verifiable example stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Set up a jsfiddle with everything needed to show the problem.

Comment: Your code could use some cleanup. Biggest issue that I see is that you have block elements inside of inline elements ie you have placed `input` tags inside of `<span>` tags and this is going to cause a problem. Can you try to change your `<span>` tags into `<div>` tags like this example? https://jsfiddle.net/noahjwhitmore/Lk445xsw/

Comment: @wazz Thanks! I added the exact code that is reproducing my problem. @Noah Whitmore Are `input` tags block-level elements? I didn't realize that. However, when I change the `span`s into `div`s, it brings up a whole new set of problems instead. I had them as `span`s because I had other `textarea`s above "Location" that I needed to be on the same line as their text descriptors, so I thought `span`s were proper to use in that case.

Comment: Has anyone thought of any sort of fix to this yet? I have still been struggling to find any sort of resolution. I tried forcing reflow of the page with the focus() method on an element, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what caused the page to not reload in its previous state, but changing the inline `span`s to `div`s with `display: inline-block` (along with a few other things) fixed the issue! See this snippit for an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var textArea = $("#TextArea1");
  var dateSpan = $("#DateSpan0");
  var theCounter = 1;

  $("#plus").click(function() {
    var theLocation =
      "<div class='formRow'><input class='inp' type='text' name='Loc" +
      theCounter +
      "'></div>";
    var theDate =
      "<div class='formRow'><input class='inp' type='text' name='Date" +
      theCounter +
      "'> <b>in</b></div>";

    $(textArea).append(theLocation);
    $(dateSpan).append(theDate);

    theCounter++;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(90, 90, 96);
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
}
fieldset,
legend {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
.addP {
  float: left;
  min-width: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative; /*for AP img*/
  padding-right: 50px; /*for AP img*/
  margin: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.formGroup {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.heading {
  float: left;
  min-width: 5em;
  background: #fff;
}
.inp {
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 137);
  border-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#plus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
}
#plus span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

#plus:focus span {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addP">
  <div class="wrap">
    <fieldset>
      <legend class="heading"><span class="heading">Location:</span></legend>
      <div id="TextArea1" class="formGroup">
        <div class="formRow">
          <input class="inp" type="text" name="Loc0">
          <button title="Add field" type="button" id="plus"><span>+</span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <fieldset>
      <legend class="heading"><span class="heading date">Date:</span></legend>
      <div id="DateSpan0" class="formGroup">
        <div class="formRow">
          <input class="inp" type="text" name="Date0">
          <b>in</b></div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```